# Can anyone tell me what I've inherited here?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

[image: fallenbikewee!!]

This is classic for my town. I'm trading this bike for a 4 Runner and would see if its even up to par. I'm not one to hit and run, as I'm usually the one getting hit, but maybe this guy is better than the 4 Runner?

Comment: Front wheels is too big for the fork (look where the front brake pads are relative to the rim. (Unless the front wheel is not in the fork dropouts.) No rear brake installed either.

Comment: You've inherted very messy room with some cartoons, bedding, raw wood table and men's bicycle. A lot of work for you to be able to move in. Good luck!

Comment: I can tell from the photo that it's a bike.  If you don't want it and you can get a decent trade on it, go for it!

Comment: Some other bike has a too-small front wheel because of this one :-\

Comment: Front wheel too big with useless front brakes and the thing seems to have no rear brakes at all, although this might only be an illusion due to the rather blurry picture.

Comment: Are clearer images possible?

Answer (score 1):

You have a front-suspension mountain bike from the 90's or 2000's

It is probably made from steel, based on the tube diameters.  Test this with a magnet.

Brake levers up on the flat bar are hard to see but seem to be metal.  That's much better than plastic levers.

The rear brake appears to be missing, or its lost in the photo.
The front brake is a V brake and is in the wrong place relative to the braking track on the front wheel.  Therefore its the wrong sized front wheel, someone's put a 27.5" wheel in a 26" wheel fork.

The front suspension looks odd - a bike of that vintage would normally have rubber stanchion boots protecting the sliding surfaces.  Perhaps someone has cut them off, or they may have simply perished.

It appears to have pod shifters (trigger shifters) which are indexed and nicer than friction shifters.

---

In short, its a nice old bike that needs work to make it safe and usable again.  But given time and effort it can be ridden again.

We don't do monetary valuations here, because that's considered off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

That's a Chris King headset. The forks and stem also look to be good quality items.

Comment: And what does that mean in terms of age, or originality?   Does this mean the bike has had a replacement fork/stem ?   Please use edit to expand your answer with additional relevant information.